# Could T'Pol still be alive in the 24th century?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

Could T'Pol still be alive during the TNG time period, since Vulcans have a life span of over 200 years?

Comment: [Apparently,](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/233-star-trek/69600790) T'Pol was born in 2088 and so would have been 286 years old, over the maximum Vulcan lifespan, by the time TNG started.

Comment: In Star Trek, anything is possible. However, assuming no contact with a Companion-type entity or exposure to cell-rejuvenating radiation, it's unlikely that T'Pol would have still been alive by that point.

Comment: I hope so!​​​​​

Comment: Dr. McCoy appears in TNG at age 137, which is well above the 20th century life expectancy for humans, so it's plausible that there are Vulcans in their 300's or even 400's around here and there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

T'Pol was born in either 2088 or 2089, because she tells Trip on her next birthday she will be 66 years old [*"Zero Hour"*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Zero_Hour_(episode)). The Enterprise D's plaque says stardate 40759.5 (2363). That would make her 275 years old when Picard takes command of the new flagship. It is unlikely she lived to that age.

In the alternate reality seen in [*"E<sup>2</sup>"*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/E%C2%B2_(episode)), where the Enterprise crew was thrown into the past and then later the crew met the current Enterprise, T'Pol was 187 years of age, and was looking rather worse for wear.

T'Pol also suffered from neurological issues as a result of her exposure and later addiction to Trellium-D. That probably didn't extend her life any.

Comment: I think you mean "The Enterprise D's plaque" as in one of those metal thingies with engravings rather than "The Enterprise D's plague" which is what rats spread.

Comment: @pharap maybe the Enterprise is a plague...